# Adjust JTextField default alignment

Tags: java, alignment, jtextfield

I created 10 JTextFields, and now I want to align them to the right. I know this can be done with `[nameTextField].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);`, but I wonder if this can be done with one line of code. Since `JTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);`, does not work, my question is: is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since `JTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);` does not work

Let's understand why that doesn't work first. If we look at the documentation for `JTextField` we can see all the methods it contains under the [*Method Summary* heading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#method_summary). It has a method `setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)`, which returns `void`. Note that the method is not declared as `static` (look in the leftmost column where it says `void`). Since the method is not static, we cannot call it on the class itself, but only on instances of the class.

> Is this possible?

I think you have two options here:

1. You can subclass `JTextField`, name it something such as `RightAlignedTextField`, and have it set the alignment by default. You can then use this instead of the plain ol' `JTextField`. OR
2. You can write a method to adjust the alignment of all the text fields you plan to use.

To use both in an example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class RightAlignedTextField extends JTextField {
    public RightAlignedTextField(int columns) {
        super(columns);
        this.setHorizontalAlignment(RIGHT);
    }
}
public class Q21970358 extends JFrame {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    private JTextField t1 = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField t2 = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField t3 = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField t4 = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField t5 = new JTextField(30);
    private JTextField t6 = new RightAlignedTextField(30);
    public Q21970358() {
        super("Stack Overflow Q21970358");
        this.addTextFields();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    }
    public void alignAllRight(JTextField... fields) {
        for (JTextField t : fields) {
            t.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        }
    }
    public void addTextFields() {
        // Set all to align right
        // This is the part you're looking for
        // (2)
        this.alignAllRight(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(t1);
        panel.add(t2);
        panel.add(t3);
        panel.add(t4);
        panel.add(t5);
        panel.add(t6); // (1)
        this.add(panel);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { new Q21970358(); }
}
```